# How to free memory on Dictionary in static class?

Tags: c#, wcf, garbage-collection, dictionary

I have a problem with freeing memory in C#. I have a static class containing a static dictionary, which is filled with references to objects. Single object zajumie large amount of memory. From time to time I release the memory by deleting obsolete references to the object set to null and remove the item from the dictionary. Unfortunately, in this case, the memory is not slowing down, time after reaching the maximum size of the memory in the system is as if a sudden release of unused resources and the amount of memory used correctly decreases.
Below is the diagram of classes:

```
public class cObj
{
    public DateTime CreatedOn;
    public object ObjectData;
}

public static class cData
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, cObj> ObjectDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, cObj>();
    public static FreeData()
    {
        foreach(var o in ObjectDict)
        {
            if (o.Value.CreatedOn <= DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-30))
            {
                cObj Data;
                if (ObjectDict.TryGetValue(o.Key, out Data))
                {
                    Data.Status = null;
                    Data.ObjectData = null;
                    ObjectDict.TryRemove(o.Key, out Data);
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

In this case, the memory is released. If, however, after this operation, I call
`GC.Collect ();`
Followed by the expected release of unused objects.

How to solve the problem, so you do not have to use the `GC.Collect()`?

Comment: Where `a` come from? What is `ResultDict`?

Comment: Sorry. Already corrected the code.

Comment: Generally speaking, the GC does its work when it's necessary. By any chance, is this running in Silverlight or some other platform? I believe they tend to request memory allocation in chunks beyond what they currently need and hold onto it for future usage for performance. (I may be wrong on this, but I'm sure I read it from a site from somewhere by someone at some point...)

Comment: I use this in a WCF service.

Comment: I've heard that using `GC.Collect()` is a bad practice. Is this the case, it is reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to call GC.Collect() in most cases. [To GC.Collect or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248838/to-gc-collect-or-not)

I've had similar scenarios where I've just created a dictionary that's limited to n entries, I did this myself on top of ConcurrentDictionary but you could use BlockingCollection.

One possible advantage is that if 1 million entries get added at the same time, all except n will be available for garbage collection rather than 30 seconds later.